Why do user-defined Windows 11 environment variables not work fully?
At the command line, I type
set var = xxx

then
set var

and I get the response
var = xxx

as expected.
If I then type
echo %var%

I get the response
%var%

not, as I'd expect
xxx

If, however, I type
echo %path%

the response is the path sequence, as I'd expect.
What am I missing?

You actually defined a variable called var  (note the extra space on the right hand side), not var.
> set var = xxx

> set var
var = xxx

> echo %var%
%var%

> echo %var %
 xxx

> set var=xxx

> set var
var=xxx
var = xxx

> echo %var%
xxx


Thank you, thank you, thank you, Ian. I thought it had to be something reallt silly ... and I wasn't wrong, was I ?!!!
